# Does "シャッターチャンス" have the same connotations as "photo op" in English?

Tags: translation, meaning

In English, the term [photo op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_op), short for photo opportunity, can mean an opportunity to take a photo, but in politics and PR, it can also mean an event staged for photos. Does "シャッターチャンス" (wasei-eigo based on "shutter chance") have the same connotations? If not, how would I refer to a photo op in the politics/PR sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Does "シャッターチャンス" (wasei-eigo based on "shutter chance") have the same connotations?"

No, absolutely not.  The word 「シャッターチャンス」 is ***not*** used for the "other" meaning you mentioned.

> "If not, how would I refer to a photo op in the politics/PR sense?"

I do not think that there is an exact equivalent everyone would agree on that actually "feels" like "photo op" for that sense.

You will, however, encounter in the news terms such as 「[写真撮影時間]{しゃしんさつえいじかん}」、「写真撮影の[機会]{きかい}」、「カメラマンとの[会見]{かいけん}」, etc.

To clarify, a cameraman might say to himself or another something like 「[今]{いま}がいいシャッターチャンスだ！」 at a photo op, but the event itself is not called 「シャッターチャンス」.